# submit nameless form with jquery anchor

Tags: jquery, database, forms

I am trying to use a link to submit a form, the kicker is I do not know the form name.  I can not seem to navigate to my form object.

```
$('a#deleteRecord').click(function(){
var $target = $(this).parent().next('form');
$target.submit();
});
```

The from is.

```
<form method="post" action=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete"/>
<input type="hidden" name="record" value="1"/>
<a id="deleteRecord" class="btn btn-danger" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

Because I am creating the form from a database it is not practical to name the form.  Can someone please help me with this code, or suggest a better solution.  Thank you

Comment: Think of it like this. `<a>` is wrapped in `<form></form>`. That form is the `.parent()` because it is the next element up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need `next()`, the form is direct parent of your anchor so [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) would be enough. The `form` tag in `html` is not closed, you need to add `</form>` to close form tag.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N4APu/)**

```
var $target = $(this).parent();
```

> Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements,
>   optionally filtered by a selector, [jQuery Doc](https://api.jquery.com/parent/).

If your want to find the parent multiple levels up in the DOM hierarchy then using [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is quite handy.

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree, [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: Didn't work.  When I do $target[0].nodeName it shows me target is a div $target.submit brings me to the .php# but the form isn't executed.

Comment: I see it working in the Live Demo,  for some reason even when I copy that code over I am getting return of div.

Comment: You might have different html, can you make a demo on jsfiddle to re-produce the problem?

Comment: Your form tag is not closed in html you have in question, check if that is the cause of problem?

Comment: the form html was closed.  I had it in a table but not in a tr or td.  I'm not sure why that glitched it, but once I cleaned that up it worked.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('a#deleteRecord').click(function () {
    var $target = $(this).closest('form');
    $target.submit();
});
```

Comment: This makes sense, but is not working.  I cannot even alert($target) when I am using closest()

Comment: @user3304548 are there multiple forms like that and multiple delete links